# Copying to a different workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy cells from my active workbook into an existing workbook in the same folder. I used the code provided that everyone said would work, but I am getting a

> "runtime error 9 Subscript out of range.

I am certain I've referenced my workbook paths correctly. I have put this code into module 1 inside my active workbook.

```
Sub foo()

Dim x As Workbook

Dim y As Workbook


Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\mhenry\Desktop\Capital Simulation\Layout.xlsm")

Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\mhenry\Desktop\Capital Simulation\ppp.xlsx")

x.Worksheets("Capital Simulation").Range("B4").Copy



x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

x.Close

End Sub
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which line is highlighted when the error is thrown?

Comment: Hi Scott, it is the x.Worksheets("Capital Simulation").Range("B4").Copy

Comment: Then you have a misspelling in the worksheet name.  double check that sheet name is correct and there are no spaces or other non visible text in the name.

Comment: Yeah I tripple chacked all of that, but no matter what I referrence, I always get this error. Is my Macro is in Module 1 under the Layout.xlsm, I copied the file path directly from the file finder and entered the file name exactly as it appears. I also made sure there are no spaces.

Comment: Both workbooks open so the file paths are correct, so the only thing that could be wrong is the sheet references, but I checked those as well, and they are in fact the same.

Comment: Sometimes the sheet name will have a space at the front or the end that you don't notice. or 2 spaces between the words. Instead of referencing it by name, try referencing it by index to see if that could be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than copy and paste you can assign the value.

```
x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").value = x.Worksheets("Capital Simulation").Range("B4").value
```